# How to create long table for my dissertation in Latex

Tags: tables, longtable

I am using Overleaf and try to insert the following table?

[image]

Comment: What's the question? (And  why did you set the `biblatex` tag?)

Comment: I am trying to design like this table for my dissertation. but not fit in same size and it suppose to be continue to next page

Answer (score 3):

As starting point may serve the following long table skeleton. It use `tabularray`, `itemize` and `etoolbox` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry} 

%%%% begin of required preamble
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}                       % <---

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtblr}%
{
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                  label=\textbullet,
                  leftmargin=*,
                  after=\end{minipage},
                  before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
                    }
}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text filler
%%%% end of required preamble

\begin{document}

%%%% begin of the table code
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = caption text,
  label = {tab:?}
                ]{
    rowhead = 1,
    hlines, vlines,
    colspec = {X[0.5,c,m] X[h,j] X[h,j]},
    colsep  = 4pt,
    row{1}  = {font=\small\bfseries, c},
    measure = vbox,
                }
text    &   text        &   text    \\
%
text
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
    \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
        \end{itemize}   
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
        \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
            \end{itemize}   \\
text
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
    \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
        \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
            \end{itemize}   \\
text
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
    \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
        \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
            \end{itemize}   \\
text
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
    \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
        \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
            \end{itemize}   \\
text
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
    \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
        \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
            \end{itemize}   \\
text
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
    \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
        \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
            \end{itemize}   \\
\end{longtblr}
%%%% end of the table code

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I test it but gave me an error. please with out \begin{document} because I want to insert the table between my text ?

Comment: @Nasser, I test my MWE (Minimal Working Example). Result of compilation is shown in answer. I test again and compilation result has no errors, no warnings, no bad boxes. So what error you got? Since you not provide any information about your document, how you test my MWE ,I have any idea what you doing.

Comment: @Nasser - You need to copy (a) the preamble material -- the stuff between `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}` -- into the preamble of *your* document, and (b) the body material -- the stuff between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` -- into the body of *your* document.

Comment: @Mico, thank you for clarification in your comment! Now I see what problem OP have And add some comments to my code.