# Create long table in LaTeX

Tags: tables, longtable, overleaf

I want to create a three-column long table, the second column has items as well as the third, as shown in the figure below, and it can fix in dissertation format and extend to the next page if needed.

[image]

I am using the following code:

```
    { 


\begingroup
\small % optional
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = The benefits and drawbacks of various gait analysis systems,
  label = {tab:b1}
  ]{
    rowhead = 1,
    hlines, vlines,
    colspec = {X[0.55,c,m] X[h,j] X[h,j]},
    colsep  = 4pt,
    row{1}  = {font=\small\bfseries, c},
   }

Technologies \& Ref. & Remarks & Limitations \\

% first major block
    Motion capture camera \newline
    [2], [9], [50]
    &   
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Gold standard gait analysis system
    \item Over virtual modeling, it provides strong and exact capture of real motions
    \item \dots
    \end{itemize}   
    &   
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Only for experiments with active line-of-sight, a particular setup is required
    \item Faster movement needs a higher sampling rate
    \item \dots
    \end{itemize}   \\
   
% next major block 
    \dots \newline [4], [5], [6]
    & 
    \begin{itemize}
    \item \dots here some indication
    \item \dots here some indication
    \end{itemize}
    & 
    \begin{itemize}
    \item \dots here some indication
    \item \dots here some indication
    \item \dots here some indication
    \end{itemize}

\end{longtblr}
\endgroup


}
```

It produce the table with black ground as shown:
[image]

Comment: Which document class are you using? Could you please add a minimal example of what you tried so far?

Comment: Off-topic: I would write "line-of-sight", not "line-of-site".

Comment: You repeat the same question again and again. Why?  Are answer on your first such question not solve your problem? If not, what then is your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Your question is actually duplicate to your [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/639422/how-to-create-long-table-for-my-dissertation-in-latex) . Answer on it solve your problem as well the problem which you repeat here again. Let me repeat there provided MWE with suggestion, how can be solved your problem.

**Edit:**

- Finally you provide a part of essential information how you write your document (by adding to tags a ˙Overleaf` tag) however we still don't know your document layout, used documentclass etc. (so I open your question)
- Unfortunately Overleaf use old `tabularray package (from July 2021), which not jet defined` j` column formation option.
- You have two option to resolve this problem
- temporally till to the time, when Overleaf will upgrade its LaTeX installation (TeXLive 2022) delete option `j`. Text in columns with `itemize` lists will become visible, buta a wee bit less nice formatted.

  - ask Overleaf support how you can add to your account there a recent version (2022A) of the `tabularray` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry} 

%%%% begin of required preamble
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}                       % <---

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtblr}%
{
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                  label=\textbullet,
                  leftmargin=*,
                  after=\end{minipage},
                  before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
                    }
}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text filler
%%%% end of required preamble

\begin{document}

%%%% begin of the table code
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = caption text,
  label = {tab:?}
                ]{
    rowhead = 1,
    hlines, vlines,
    colspec = {X[0.5,c,m] X[h] X[h]}, % temporary until tabularray
                                      % version 2022A will not be 
                                      % available in Overleaf
    % colspec = {X[0.5,c,m] X[h,j] X[h,j]},
    colsep  = 4pt,
    row{1}  = {font=\small\bfseries, c},
    measure = vbox,
                }
text    &   text        &   text    \\
%
text
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
    \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
        \end{itemize}   
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
        \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
            \end{itemize}   \\
text
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
    \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
        \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
            \end{itemize}   \\
text
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
    \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
        \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
            \end{itemize}   \\
text
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
    \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
        \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
            \end{itemize}   \\
text
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
    \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
        \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
            \end{itemize}   \\
text
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
    \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
        \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
            \end{itemize}   \\
\end{longtblr}
%%%% end of the table code

\end{document}
```

-All answers are usual given in MWE (Minimal Working form), a small but complete document, which contain:

- `\documentclass{...}`
- preamble with packages, which had to be loaded that MWE can be compiled and had to be add to your document preamble if they aren't already loaded there
- `begin{document}`, which star document body
- document body with suggestion how to solve your problem
- `\end{document}`
- From above follows, that in your document you need to add only body of provided document and check if your document preamble load all needed packages. Missed one copy from answer to your preamble.
- As I can conclude from your questions, you need to make your self more familiar with LaTeX. Reading some introductory text about it, as it for example [The Not So Short Introduction to LATEX 2ε](https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf), will help you to understand LaTeX better.
- And on the end, please always provide a MWE, which reproduce your problem. With this you will help us to help you. And also not repeat the same question three time. Ones is sufficient.

Image of table produced in my answer, which MWE is copied above:

[image]

Comment: It shows me a dark in two columns ( remark and limitation )

Comment: @Nasser, with my MWE for sure not. You need to show us, what you doing. Apparently you change something. You still not show as a MWE, which reproduce your problem.

Comment: It shows me a black ground in two columns ( Remarks and Limitations ) and error said : Undefined color 'j'

Comment: @Nasser, on such a way we will not solve your problem. Show me your MWE, which reproduce your problem. My MWE works (tested many times with recent MiKTeX). As possible solution of your problem is outdated LaTeX installation.  Try to upgrade it.

Comment: I can't post a screen shot here

Comment: @Nasser, I didn't ask for screenshot. I ask for code (copy it from your editor and past in your question.  Tel me, do you maybe use of Overleaf for your project? If yes, than (i) add tag `overleaf` to your question, and (ii) ask Overleaf support, how to install recent `tabularray` package to your account. Till to publishing of the TeXLive 2022 it will have outdated version of `tabularray` package. Even better, install for example MiKTeX on your computer.

Comment: @Nasser, see edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a long table, you can use the `longtable` package.

You must include `\usepackage{longtable}` in the preamble. Later, you must use `\begin{longtable}` and close it with `\end{longtable}`.

A very simple example,

```
\documentclass[landscape,12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{longtable}
  \begin{document}
     \centering
     \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
      \begin{longtable}{|p{2in}|p{2in}|p{2in}|}\hline
      First Column Content & Second Column Content & Third Column Content\\\hline
      \end{longtable}
```

The code above will help get the result your are looking for.

Happy TeXting!

Comment: Umm, *never* encase a `longtable` environment in a `center` environment.